Norm of the triangular $SL(2)$-matrix
Let $A=\begin{pmatrix}
4 & 0 \\
1 & \frac{1}{4}
\end{pmatrix}$. What is the supremum norm $\|A^2\|$? Recall that $\|A\|:=\sup\{\frac{|Av|}{|v|}: v\neq 0\}$.
Attempt: $A^2=\begin{pmatrix}
4^2 & 0 \\
4+\frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{4^2}
\end{pmatrix}$. I thought I should calculate the first singular value, which is the equal of the norm, to find the value of the norm. I was wondering if there was the simple way as I want to calculate the higher power, e.g., $A^{15}$.
In general, I want to know whether this is true for $SL(2)$ matrices, one should look at the diagonal entries or not to calculate the norm.

As the result is quite horrible, I don't think there is a nice way of doing this.

The initial approach is fine:
$$
A^2 = 
\left(
\begin{array}{cc} 
4 & 0 \\ 
1 & \frac{1}{4} 
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{cc} 
4 & 0 \\ 
1 & \frac{1}{4} 
\end{array}
\right) 
= 
\left(
\begin{array}{cc} 
16 & 0 \\ 
\frac{17}{4} & \frac{1}{16} 
\end{array}
\right)= \frac{1}{16}
\left(
\begin{array}{cc} 
256 & 0 \\ 
68 & 1
\end{array}
\right)
$$
What you need to do next is calculate the product of the transpose of the matrix in question and the matrix itself, that is, $(A^2)^T A^2$. Let's proceed to do so:
$$
(A^2)^T A^2 =
\frac{1}{16}
\left(
\begin{array}{cc} 
256 & 68 \\ 
0 & 1
\end{array}
\right)
\frac{1}{16}
\left(
\begin{array}{cc} 
256 & 0 \\ 
68 & 1
\end{array}
\right)=
\frac{1}{256}
\left(
\begin{array}{} 
70160 & 68 \\ 
68 & 1
\end{array}
\right)
$$
As we've done it, we need to calculate the characteristic polynomial of that monster, not including the factor $\frac{1}{256}$, aka taking $\mu=256\lambda$):
$$
\det{|(A^2)^T A^2 - \mu I|} = (70160-\mu)(1-\mu)-68^2=0 \Leftrightarrow
\mu^2 - 70161 \mu + 65536 = 0
$$
From here, it is easy to find:
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{cl}
\mu_1 &=& \frac{70161}{2} + \frac{17 \sqrt{17032193}}{2} \\
\mu_2 &=& \frac{70161}{2} - \frac{17 \sqrt{17032193}}{2}
\end{array}
\right.
$$
Or, turning back to actual $\lambda$:
From here, it is easy to find:
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{cl}
\lambda_1 &=& \frac{70161}{512} + \frac{17 \sqrt{17032193}}{512} \\
\lambda_2 &=& \frac{70161}{512} - \frac{17 \sqrt{17032193}}{512}
\end{array}
\right.
$$
Now, to find the norm, you have to take the square root of the largest eigenvalue:
$$
\vert| A^2 \vert| = \sqrt{\lambda_1} = \sqrt{\frac{70161}{512} + \frac{17 \sqrt{17032193}}{512}}
$$

Recall that $$\|A\|:=\sup\{\frac{|Av|}{|v|}: v\neq 0\}=\sup\{|Av|: |v|=1\}.$$
Let $v=\binom{\cos t}{\sin t}$ and then
$$ \begin{eqnarray}
|A^2v|^2&=&\bigg|\begin{pmatrix}
4^2 & 0 \\
4+\frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{4^2}
\end{pmatrix}\binom{\cos t}{\sin t}\bigg|^2=\bigg|\binom{16\cos t}{\frac{17}{4}\cos t+\frac1{16}\sin t}\bigg|^2\\
&=&256\cos^2t+\bigg(\frac{17}{4}\cos t+\frac1{16}\sin t\bigg)^2\\
&=&\frac{4385}{16}\cos^2t+\frac{17}{32}\cos t\sin t+\frac{1}{256}\sin^2t\\
&=&\frac{4385}{32}(1+\cos(2t))+\frac{17}{64}\sin 2t+\frac{1}{512}(1-\cos(2t))\\
&=&\frac{1}{512} (136 \sin (2 t)+70159 \cos (2 t)+70161). 
\end{eqnarray}$$
So
$$ \begin{eqnarray}
\sup\{|A^2v|^2,|v|=1\}&=&\max_{t}\sqrt{\frac{1}{512} (136 \sin (2 t)+70159 \cos (2 t)+70161)}\\
&=&\frac{1}{512} (\sqrt{136^2+70159^2}+70161)\\
&=&\frac{1}{512} (17\sqrt{17032193}+70161) 
\end{eqnarray} $$
and hence
$$ \|A^2\|=\sup\{|A^2v|,|v|=1\}=\frac{1}{16} \sqrt{2(17\sqrt{17032193}+70161)}. $$
